# Android - Google Map on +-180 longitude and 90 latitude

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I have implemented a MapFragment with an xml layout like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/activity_mappa_partenza" />
```

In Google map api v.2 I want to draw a Polygon:

```
PolygonOptions optionsShadow = new PolygonOptions();
optionsShadow.fillColor(Color.RED);
optionsShadow.strokeColor(Color.RED);
optionsShadow.strokeWidth(1f);
optionsShadow.addAll(ombraLinkList);
map.addPolygon(optionsShadow);
```

ombraLinkList is a LinkedList filled with all point from Sun Terminator Line

What I want to achieve is a polygon filled with night region of the earth.

If the Latitude and Longitude are of this type:
    Lat 90  Lon -180,
    Lat 78  Lon -150,
    Lat 75  Lon -120,
    --------
    ---------
    Lat 35  Lon -45,
    Lat 55  Lon 0,
    Lat 65  Lon 20,
    Lat 75  Lon 45,
    Lat 80  Lon 75,
    Lat 90  Lon 180

Lat 90,  Lon 180 is the same point of Lat 90,  Lon -180  and i'm unable to
draw and close the poligon area.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in GIS when drawing polygon the start point is the same as end point ("closed polygon"). So use (90,180) as this start-end point. Also usually the order of the coordinates in the list matters. So just remove coordinates (90,-180) if (90,180) exist and make sure (90,180) is the first and the last in the list.

EDIT:

The data type of the list of coordinates is `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng` and pay attention to the [specification](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) which is:

> Longitude, in degrees. This value is in the range **[**-180, 180 **)**
>
> Latitude, in degrees. This value is in the range **[**-90, 90 **]**.

Which means ain't collisions. So you tried (90,180) as start-end, so now we know that in Google maps GIS system it should be (90,-180)...

Comment: I have already try this...but without solution...the polygon is not closed

Comment: @sat70 What is the data type of your linked list? it shoukd be LatLng object

Comment: Thanks for your reply...my data type is LatLng..but i think there's some strange behavior when around +-180 longitude.
I found a partial solution by using stroke color transparent and one last point to be 179.999 instead of 180....

Comment: @sat70 It hard to believe Google will miss that... Did you tried what I wrote using (90,-180)? and not (90,180)? Did you order the list?

Comment: yes i tried what you suggest - I think it's the same problem mentioned here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011748/drawing-a-polygon-over-the-entire-map)
the problem on floating point calculation in fact firstable with 179.5 I have a thin line
I'm not sure but i think it's related to this problem:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430096/double-precision-value-computation-errors-on-mediatek-processors)